# Get username in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Does anyone know, how to get the username in Android using C# Xamarin?

I mean, when you in Android open:

> Settings > System > About phone > [Name at the top] ?

Or:

> Settings > System > About phone > Multiple users > You (the name) ?

I'm only interested in the user (display) name and not the e-mail nor the device name (which is not the same as the username).

I've tried with `await Contacts.GetAllAsync()` using the required permissions, but the result was always empty.

Then I've tried with `Environment.UserName`, but this returned "somebody"...

I did also found [this post](https://doumer.me/get-the-device-current-user-name-with-xamarin-forms/), but my code not find either the `User` class or the `CrossCurrentActivity` class that is mentioned in the code in the post...

Also the post describes installing a [CurrentActivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/CurrentActivity) plugin, but the page doesn't exist anymore...

I'm using Xamarin Forms with Shell (latest version) and Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

My Android version is 9.0.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

See this picture from the settings of my Android emulated device for explanation of, what I mean:

[image]

Comment: User is only used in the UWP code, not the Android code.  CurrentActivity is now part of Essentials - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.platform.currentactivity?view=xamarin-essentials-android

Comment: Xamarin Essentials does not provide this information. You'll have to do it "by hand". 
Check this blogpost => https://doumer.me/get-the-device-current-user-name-with-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

For your needs, **Xamarin.Essentials** has a special method to get your **Device Information**.

1. Download Xamarin.Essential in Nuget.
2. Use `var deviceName = DeviceInfo.Name;` to get it.

For more information, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer my question.

`var deviceName = DeviceInfo.Name` returns "AOSP on IA Emulator" on my virtuel Android emulated device, but the username (displayname) is "Owner".

See screen shot above.

How to get the displayname/username of the owner of the device ???

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class UserInformation : IUserInformation
    {
        /*  Caution: This method returns personal and sensitive user data.If your app accesses, collects, uses, or shares personal and sensitive data, 
         *  you must clearly disclose that fact to users. For apps published on Google Play, policies protecting user data require that you do the following:
         *  Disclose to the user how your app accesses, collects, uses, or shares personal and sensitive data. Learn more about acceptable disclosure and consent.
         * Provide a privacy policy that describes your use of this data on- and off-device.
         * To learn more, visit the Google Play Policy regarding user data. */

        public Task<string> GetUserName()
        {
            FormsAppCompatActivity activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity as FormsAppCompatActivity;

            AccountManager manager = AccountManager.Get(activity);
            Account[] accounts = manager.GetAccounts();     // .GetAccountsByType("com.google");   "Type = "com.osp.app.signin" ?
            List<String> emails = new List<string>();

            foreach (Account account in accounts)
            {
                //var name = account.Name;
                emails.Add(account.Name);
            }

            // Should Loop until find one with "name"
            if (emails.Any() && emails[0] != null)
            {
                String email = emails[0];
                String[] parts = email.Split('@');

                if (parts.Length > 1)
                {
                   return Task.FromResult(parts[0]);
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult("");
        }
    }
```